# php disable user to access certain page unless login

Tags: php

i am new to php and i want to ask something, is it possible for us to make a feature like state below?
i have several admin page, and have a admin login page. and for normal routine it should be fine. but if someone know the url of the admin page that are after the login page, all they need to do is just to type that url and access that page to make changes, but i want to disable it, so it will ask them to login as admin in order to view that page and redirect them to the admin login pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set userid  to  session on login   and check that session is set if not set redirect to other page or dont include certain part of code or whole code up to you

like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
   //redirect or other you want
}
```

Comment: @shuffle1990 **Always** use something like this when protecting pages, security through obscurity is a **terrible** practice.